# Adding dependencies to static library using CMake in Visual studio 2017 does not work

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, dependencies, static-libraries

I'm trying to convert a big project (with executable, dynamic libraries and static libraries) to use the CMake build system. I have issues adding dependencies to static libraries.

I have a root CMake which will call a list of sub directories

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8.0)
project(CC)
add_subdirectory(SmartCardUtility)
add_subdirectory(CertificateUtil)
..
```

The CMakeLists.txt file under the CertificateUtil looks like below.

```
project(CertificateUtil CXX)
source grouping....
include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Output/_INC_DEV")
link_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../OpenSSL")
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${ALL_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} libcrypto)
```

In the above piece of code, if the add_library is replaced by add_executable or add_library with SHARED, then the dependencies are resolved correctly and show up in the Additional_Dependencies but for the static lib, the Additional_Dependencies in the property page is always empty.

After surfing through the net around this point, I understand target_link_libraries command doesn't add anything in the Librarian. Then the question is, what is the right way to add dependencies to static libraries so they show up in the Additional_Dependencies under Librarian?

I tried to add the dependencies as imported objects like below but still it doesn't work.

```
add_library(libcrypto OBJECT IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET libcrypto PROPERTY  IMPORTED_OBJECTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../OpenSSL/libcrypto.lib")
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${ALL_FILES} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:libcrypto>)
```

Comment: "what is the right way to add dependencies to static libraries so they show up in the Additional_Dependencies under Librarian?" Static libraries are **not linked**, so I am not sure what do you want to see in the `Additional Dependencies` field which is intended for the linker.

Comment: Currently in the visual studio project that I'm trying to port, I see some OpenSSL  libraries included in Librarian -> General -> Additional Dependencies and the corresponding path included in Librarian -> General -> Additional Library Directories. How can I achieve this through CMake? without adding this, the build results before and after CMake are not the same.