CMake Replicate Visual Studio Static Lib Generating Static Lib with Additional Dependencies
I'm new to CMake and I'm trying to make a static library that I can use across different applications.
I have MyLibrary CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# Set the project name
project(MyLibrary)

# Specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(BUILD_MODE "x64" CACHE STRING "Build mode: x64 or Win32")

# Collect all source files, including MyLibrary and GUI implementations
file(GLOB_RECURSE GUI_SOURCES src/GUI/*.cpp)
set(SOURCES
    src/MyLibrary.cpp
    ${GUI_SOURCES} # Add collected GUI sources
)

# Define the library target
add_library(MyLibrary STATIC ${SOURCES})

# Link the third-party libraries (PUBLIC to propagate)
target_link_libraries(MyLibrary PUBLIC 
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ThirdParty/GLFW/lib/${BUILD_MODE}/glfw3.lib
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ThirdParty/GLEW/lib/${BUILD_MODE}/glew32s.lib
    opengl32.lib
)

# Include directories for public headers
target_include_directories(MyLibrary PUBLIC
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/GUI # Add GUI include folder
)

# Include directories for third-party libraries
target_include_directories(MyLibrary PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ThirdParty/GLFW/include
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ThirdParty/GLEW/include
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ThirdParty/GLM
)

I build MyLibrary with these commands:
cmake -S . -B build 
cmake --build .\build\

This generates a MyLibrary.lib but when I try using it in a sample application like this MyApplication:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(MyApplication)

# Add the executable
add_executable(MyApplication src/main.cpp)

# Link MyLibrary
target_link_libraries(MyApplication PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../MyLibrary/build/Debug/MyLibrary.lib
)

# Include MyLibrary additional headers
target_include_directories(MyApplication PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../MyLibrary/include
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../MyLibrary/ThirdParty/GLFW/include
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../MyLibrary/ThirdParty/GLEW/include
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../MyLibrary/ThirdParty/GLM
)

I get "unresolved external symbol" errors because the GLFW lib is not being propagated. I can work around this by copying the target_link_libraries from MyLibrary in MyApplication but I didn't need to list all the dependencies of MyLibrary when I build it with Visual Studio.
This is possible when I generate the Static Lib with Visual Studio by adding the third-party libs in "Properties>Librarian>Additional Dependencies" and building with Visual Studio. MyApplication compile correctly when it only includes MyLibrary.lib. In the generated MyLibrary.vcxproj I see a section that lists all the libs <AdditionalDependencies></AdditionalDependencies>.
But when I build with just cmake commands, the generated MyLibrary.vcxproj is missing AdditionalDependencies and the generated MyLibrary.lib is much smaller and does not propagate its dependencies. I feel like there should also be a way to do this with just CMake.
Any suggestions is appreciated.
EDIT:
This question was marked as duplicate but the duplicate post does not answer my question. I found the solution and wanted to share it since I seen this question asked multiple times without a solution.
I found this on cmake's gitlab discussion asking the same question as mine: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/16931
The discussion mentioned adding
set ( CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS} somelib.lib" )

This suggestion worked for my project:
set ( 
    CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS 
    "${CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS}
     ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ThirdParty/GLEW/lib/${BUILD_MODE}/glew32s.lib
     ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ThirdParty/GLFW/lib/${BUILD_MODE}/glfw3.lib
     opengl32.lib" 
)

This replicated the Librarian Addition Dependencies I saw when I build MyLibrary with Visual Studio. Now, I can build MyLibrary with just CMake commands and when my other projects includes MyLibrary.lib, they will also get the symbols for the dependences of MyLibrary.lib. I think this combination of multiple Static Libs is called a Fat Static Library

You need to install it specifying that you want an exported target so that the other project can import it, that's too long to fit in an answer. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/importing-exporting/index.html

For linking MyApplication with MyLibrary and its depending, MyApplication must link the target MyLibrary but you attempt to link a file. You should merge the both cmake files into a single files (or learn how to include first one into a second one, or export/import targets) and target_link_libraries(MyApplication MyLibrary)

The linked duplicate doesn't answer the question at all. Here the problem is that once MyLibrary.lib is installed in the system it doesn't contain any information about its dependencies. So, the answer should explain how to export target *.lib with corresponding FindMyLib.cmake,  MyLibTargets.cmake scripts and then use it with find_package.

I am already doing target_link_libraries as described in the duplicate question and the solution is not working.  I want to know why my CMake configuration doesn't  seem to add the third party libraries and I need to manually add them with in the MyLibrary.vcxproj in order for MyLibrary to propagate its linked Libraries

This question is also similar to the issue I'm encountering but it doesn't have an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60963643/adding-dependencies-to-static-library-using-cmake-in-visual-studio-2017-does-not
